# Value of Sum not changed after unchecked Checkbox Button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

Im looking solution for this problem.
I have 3 input number that will sum all of that and display it to input4.

All my code is working fine but only when I unchecked the checkbox, the value of sum didn't update.

Scenario example:

1. Checked on first checkbox and enter value of 1
2. Checked on second checkbox and enter value of 1. This will trigger the display value and will show result=2
3. Unchecked the first checkbox will clear the first input value, but the result display not update(still result=2.. Should be result=1)

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbxcasting" />
<input type="number" id="casting1" name="casting1" value="0" disabled onchange="valChange(this);" onkeyup="sum1();" /><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="chkbxdeburring" />
<input type="number" id="deburring1" name="deburring1" value="0" disabled onchange="valChange(this);" onkeyup="sum1();" /><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="chkbxecoat" />
<input type="number" id="ecoat1" name="ecoat1" value="0" disabled onchange="valChange(this);" onkeyup="sum1();" /><br><br>

<input class="invisibleinput" type="number" id="totalaffectqty" name="totalaffectqty" readonly />
```

CSS

```
input[value="0"] { color: #fff; }
```

Javascript + JQuery

```
function valChange(obj){
  if(obj.value=="0"){
    obj.style.color="#fff"
  } else{
    obj.style.color="#000"
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#chkbxcasting').on('change', function() {
    $("#casting1").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
    $("#casting1").val('');
  });

  $('#chkbxdeburring').on('change', function() {
    $("#deburring1").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
    $("#deburring1").val('');
  });

  $('#chkbxecoat').on('change', function() {
    $("#ecoat1").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
    $("#ecoat1").val('');
  });
});

function sum1() {
  let casting1 = +(document.getElementById('casting1').value);
  let deburring1 = +(document.getElementById('deburring1').value);
  let ecoat1 = +(document.getElementById('ecoat1').value);

  let result1 = casting1 + deburring1 + ecoat1;
  if (!isNaN(result1)) {
    document.getElementById('totalaffectqty').value = result1;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('totalaffectqty').value = '0';
  }
}
```

This is the demo:

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wanprogramming/hj453cru/1/)

Thank You in Advance

Comment: your function sum1() does not get called. you should call sum1() inside all on change function

Comment: also if all values are 0 then how is sum gonna change?

Comment: what do u mean by cal sum1() inside all on change function ?
if all 0 then there will be no changes

Comment: you have several on('change', finction() {, I said you have to call sum1() inside these functions like after $("casting").val(); and never mind my second comment, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/disingh123/szmt8rv2/3/

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkbxcasting" />
    <input type="number" id="casting1" name="casting1" value="0" disabled /><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="chkbxdeburring" />
    <input type="number" id="deburring1" name="deburring1" value="0" disabled /><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="chkbxecoat" />
    <input type="number" id="ecoat1" name="ecoat1" value="0" disabled /><br><br>

    <input class="invisibleinput" type="number" id="totalaffectqty" name="totalaffectqty" readonly />
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('change', function (event) {
        const { target: { type } } = event
        if (type === 'checkbox') {
            const jQueryFiedTarget = $(event.target)
            const isChecked = jQueryFiedTarget.is(':checked')
            const associatedTextField = jQueryFiedTarget.next()
            associatedTextField.prop("disabled", !isChecked);
            associatedTextField.val(isChecked ? '' : '0')
            if (!isChecked) {
                sum1()
            }
        }
    })

    $('body').on('keyup', function (event) {
        const { target: { type } } = event
        if (type === 'number') {
            sum1()
        }
    })
});
```

```
function sum1() {
    const casting1 = +(document.getElementById('casting1').value);
    const deburring1 = +(document.getElementById('deburring1').value);
    const ecoat1 = +(document.getElementById('ecoat1').value);
    const result1 = casting1 + deburring1 + ecoat1;
    document.getElementById('totalaffectqty').value = isNaN(result1) ? '0' : result1
}
```